# How to translate (multiple) id fields to title in phpmyadmin by using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table User has three fields (all store different group id):

```
group, additional_group, display_group
2, 3, 4
```

Another table Group has

```
id, title
2, admin
3, editor
4, subscriber
```

How to get all three fields translated to title?

Code:

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
```

Result:

```
2, 3, 4
```

Expected result:

```
admin, editor, subscriber
```

With my limited SQL knowledge, all I can come up with is translating one field:

```
SELECT *, group.title FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `group` WHERE users.group = group.id
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. Also correct that typo. And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Hint: LEFT JOIN several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` once for each title:

```
select u.*, g1.title. g2.title, g3.title
from `users` u
LEFT JOIN `group` g1 ON u.group = g1.id
LEFT JOIN `group` g2 ON u.additional_group = g2.id
LEFT JOIN `group` g3 ON u.display_group = g3.id
```

Comment: At last I did it by search-and-replace one by one in a text editor manually, which is a stupid way but I was on tight schedule. Your method is much better, I'm sure it will help people who have the same needs.Thanks!